# Dependent Picklist Not Working on Edit Opportunity Split Screen

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, dependent-picklist, opportunity-split

I've created a custom dependent picklist on the Opportunity Split objects and on testing the dependency on an individual Opp Split record it works well however on the Edit Opportunity Splits screen the Controlling field renders ok but the dependency does not.
For reference the fields are custom Country/State fields but I guess they could be any dependency based picklists.

Has anyone come across this before and if so is there a workaround that can be applied?

Thanks in advance for any help.

The following screenshot is taken from the detail of an individual Opportunity.
[image]

The following screenshot is from the Edit Opportunity Splits screen (where the state is not rendering from a Country selection)

[image]

Is there a solution without a custom LWC build?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the following all indicating issues with Dependent picklists in inline-edit.  I guess it's a well known long-term issue

https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001YoPNQA0
https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000003h2EQAQ
https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000efJwQAI
https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001HliFQAS